# What does my OPC Server need to do after OPC Client restores lost connection?

Tags: opc

I have my own OPC Server written using the SLIK-DA4 ActiveX control in VB6. It hosts quite a large collection of tags (probably 2,000).

A customer uses a Siemens OPC client to connect (no private security). Everything goes fine and subscription reads appear just fine on the client.

Some time later, the IP link is lost between client and server for a while. However, the customer is telling me that when the link recovers, they then have to "do something" on the OPC client to get it to start subscribing again, after which things return to normal.

... Yes, I know, I'm trying to find out what they mean by "do something" !!

However, in the meantime, I'm trying to think of what I *might* not be doing correctly in my server code to handle this situation. My tag values don't update too often in the attached field equipment, so is it possible that, on reconnection, the client isn't receiving any callbacks simply because there are no tag changes taking place ?

On recovery of the link, how can I get the server to push an up-to-date status for all tags to the client rather than rely on someone "doing something" on the client end ? Do I need to use the OnConnect event and then SetVQT(,,sdaSGood) for all tags, or will this not have any effect ?

Thanks

Comment: The spec does not define any action for the server in this situation. It does not even know that the connection was lost for a while. If you get OnConnect, it's because the client created a new connection, after which everything should work normally of course.

Answer (score 1):

When the OPC server receives a new connection (which seems to be the case), or more precisely, when the OPC client it creates an active group and puts items in it, the server is supposed to send an initial notification about each item (value/timestamp/quality, or error) - even if it has not changed recently.

If you are developing the server using a reasonable OPC toolkit, however, this should be taken care of automatically by the toolkit code. It certainly makes no sense to try to change the quality of the tags just because the OPC client had connected. The quality in the VQT should reflect whatever comes from your underlying system, or the communication problems communicating to THAT system, but *not* anything between the OPC server and the client.

It may also very well be a problem on the client side - simply not resilient enough to handle certain situations. The authoritative way to tell what is happening (and put the "blame" into the direction of the server or the client) would be place an OPC Analyzer (available from OPC Foundation to OPC Members) in between, and log the OPC calls and check which side is not behaving right.

Comment: EDIT:

(a) Someone at Siemens has now advised me that my server is not handling what they call a "re-open" request from their OPC Client. To be honest, I've never heard of this. What do they mean, and which of the SLIK-DA events should be handling it ?

(b) Re: the above, I am running NDISLIKDA4.DLL version 4.0.1.17. Someone at Software Toolbox has advised me to put something in my OnDataChange event handler. This version of NDISLIKDA4 doesn't have such a thing. Advice, anyone ?

Answer (score 0):

> what they mean by "do something"

I think it means that customer needs to restart the client, create a group and add tags. But this is how things should be, because OPC Specification doesn't say anything about handling of connection breaks. It has only description of interfaces which can be used to check connection (server) status (e.g. `IOPCServer::GetStatus`). Typically, clients reconnect (create a new connection with new group and add tags) automatically, but only if they have been noticed that connection was lost.

> a "re-open" request from their OPC Client

You can ask someone from Siemens to provide you quotation from OPC Specification where "re-open" mechanism and/or interfaces are described. Because I don't remember such notations in specification.

But if "re-open" means reusing of old connection (i.e. DCOM objects left from old connection) then I may assume the following situation:

- client and server interacts properly
- connection breaks
- server sends `OnDataChange` callback to client and receives an error (something like "RPC service is unavailable")
- server just stops sending of `OnDataChange` callbacks and do nothing with DCOM objects related to current connection
- connection restores
- client still can call server using existing DCOM objects but doesn't receive `OnDataChange` callbacks
- customer need to restart client manually to repair connection

In such case you (or toolkit) should remove all objects related to broken connection or don't stop sending of callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

When IP changes ,try to reconnect the OPC Server or Make your OPC Server IP address as static